# change user password from hash store function to cleartext

Tags: php, php-password-hash

im doing a [tutorial](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html) about how to make a php mysql login form.
now the tutorial is actualy made to good and i wold like to alter it a bit and change the login password to store cleartext instead of the hash. the hash line looks like this:

```
$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

i made:

```
$new_password = $upass;
```

out of it. and it now saves the cleartext to the database but the login doesn't work.

the login part looks like this and i don't see the part where i expect the hashed-password to be converted and matched...

```
public function doLogin($uname,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text is __absolutely insecure__. So if you want to use best practices - forget about plain text.

Comment: "i wold like to alter it a bit and change the login password to store cleartext". This is not something you would ever want to do in a real project, so I would recommend against using it for an exercise.

Comment: ... why are you storing passwords as clear text?

Comment: so you want to match your cleartext with `password_verify()`; am sorry to say but that won't work. `password_verify()` expects to match against a hash.

Comment: function password_verify is where it is checked, you would need to change it. but cleartext passwords are insecure. Use always HASHed passwords

Comment: "change the login password to store cleartext instead of the hash"... Just to add myself to the chorus: NOOOOO.

Comment: And we complain about bad tutorials ...

Comment: btw, you're asking/begging for trouble. If you're a sucker for punishment, then get ready for it and a LOT of it. But don't come back to us and saying your server got hacked. Because you **will** get hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
```

Checks the hash of the password against the given password. As you've removed the hashing function it's comparing an un-hashed password against a clear text password.

Change it to:

```
if($upass == $userRow['user_pass'])
```

That should fix it.

Although you ***really*** should not be storing clear text passwords.

Comment: thank you! that works! its only for a test so i don't care and the work will never go online..

Comment: That's fine, but it is good practice to get into the habit of using hashes

Answer (score 1):

If you're not hashing the passwords anymore then you can't verify the hash

```
if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
```

Should be

```
if($upass == $userRow['user_pass'])
```

Understand that this is a **very bad idea**. You might not understand [why hashing passwords is important](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords)

> For any reason, your database may be compromised and its data may be obtained by someone else. If the passwords are in what we call plain text, you will have leaked a piece of sensitive information that your users have trusted you with: their password (which is very likely to be a password shared in multiple services). This is a very serious issue.